# grouping by time difference between two columns of a table oracle sql

Tags: sql, datetime, grouping, oracle-sqldeveloper, date-difference

[In Time
Out Time

28-05-2020 16:55:54
28-05-2020 16:55:54

28-05-2020 17:04:08
28-05-2020 17:04:08

29-05-2020 23:10:46
29-05-2020 23:10:46

01-06-2020 12:52:06
01-06-2020 12:52:06

01-06-2020 12:53:11

01-06-2020 13:00:39
01-06-2020 13:00:39

01-06-2020 13:10:43
01-06-2020 13:10:44

28-05-2020 16:55:54

This how may oracle sql table displays some time stamps in two columns.

I wanted to take out difference in time by milliseconds in these two columns and then group them as count based on difference in milli seconds only where time difference is below 1000 milli seconds and both columns have valid value of time.

Difference in Milliseconds for in and out
count

3000
10

20
111

1
1000

10000
3

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU7p1.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the expected output from the example you have given above.

Comment: Hi - what have you already tried and what issues are you facing? Have you managed to calculate the difference in milliseconds? Are you struggling with the filtering or the counting?

Comment: I have two columns with time stamps of in and out . wanted to take count of number of each time gaps to do a modal or median analysis .

something like 10 m.secs 12 entries, 1 m.sec 1000 entries, 20 m.secs 2 entries..

I can take time difference between two columns of same row but i wanted a grouping query to get a map of number of entries and time differences only when both the column values are not null.

Comment: Please can you tag your question with which DB are you using (Oracle, SQL Server, Snowflake, etc?). Date/Time functions are often specific to the DB vendor so we would need to know which DB yo0u are using to be sure of giving you an answer that will work for you

Comment: Oracle SQL. it has the milliseconds if i extract in different format for a specific row.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Oracle doesn't provide a simple way of subtracting one timestamp from another and giving the answer in milliseconds. The following code should give you want you want; I've split it up into a few steps using CTEs just to make it easier to follow but you could probably simplify it.

```
WITH T1 AS ( -- CALCULATE TIME IN ms BETWEEN EACH TIMESTAMP
SELECT
    IN_TIME,
    OUT_TIME,
    extract( day from (OUT_TIME - IN_TIME) )*24*60*60*1000 +
    extract( hour from (OUT_TIME - IN_TIME) )*60*60*1000 +
    extract( minute from (OUT_TIME - IN_TIME) )*60*1000 +
    round(extract( second from (OUT_TIME - IN_TIME) )*1000) TOTAL_MS
FROM DATA1
)
,T2 AS ( -- FILTER TO INCLUDE ONLY THOSE RECORDS WITHIN THE REQUIRED DURATION
SELECT
    IN_TIME,
    OUT_TIME,
    TOTAL_MS
FROM T1
WHERE TOTAL_MS > 0 AND TOTAL_MS < 1000
)
SELECT TOTAL_MS, COUNT(1) FROM T2
GROUP BY TOTAL_MS
;
```

**Update 1**

Actually, the following works and is much simpler:

```
(OUT_TIME - IN_TIME)*24*60*60*1000 AS TOTAL_MS
```

You can also exclude "invalid" records from the 1st SELECT with a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE OUT_TIME IS NOT NULL AND IN_TIME IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: thanks for the input, this should help, still is there a way to convert any of time column into ms number directly instead of taking out day hour and minutes?